# bootstrapped confidence interval for glmer model with identity link

Tags: r, confidence-interval, lme4-nlme, bootstrap, link-function

In an experiment Subjects decide as fast as possible whether letter strings presented on screen are real Words or non-words and reaction time (RT) in milliseconds is recorded. We want to know for correct Word decisions, if Word Frequency (how often the word appears in books) affects reaction time (the answer is yes, a very robust result in psycholinguistics).

In this article https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2015.01171 it is convincingly suggested that this kind of data should be analyzed with a generalized mixed linear model using an inverse Gaussian or Gamma distribution and an *identity* link so the results can be interpreted in original units (milliseconds).

I would like to adopt this approach, but also calculate a 95% confidence interval around the fixed effect estimate for Frequency, and this is where I run into trouble. The standard bootstrapping methods available do not seem to work with a `glmer` model with identity link (error: `*all* bootstrap runs failed!`). If I change the link to a (non canonical-) log link, bootstrapping seems to work, but then I if I try to back transform the reported interval around the fixed effect using the inverse of the natural log (`exp()`) I do not get sensible values (i.e., that roughly correspond to the confidence interval that I get with using `lmer()`.

reproducible example:

```
library(lme4)
library(languageR)

data(lexdec) 

lexdec$RT.orig <- exp(lexdec$RT) # reaction time was log transformed in the data set, transforming back
lexdec$Frequency.c <- lexdec$Frequency - mean(lexdec$Frequency) # centering frequency 

# for comparison an lmer model (assuming Gaussian error) 
mod <- lmer(RT.orig ~ Frequency.c + (1 | Subject) + (1 | Word), data = lexdec)
summary(mod) # reaction time decreases with about 30 ms when wordfrequency increases by 1 
confint(mod) # 95 CI [-38, -21]

qqnorm(resid(mod)) # errors not normal


# glmer model with inverse Gaussian errors and an identity link
mod1.id <- glmer(RT.orig ~  Frequency.c + (1 | Subject) + (1 | Word), 
                 family = inverse.gaussian(link = "identity"), data = lexdec)

# model with log link 
mod1.log <- glmer(RT.orig ~ Frequency.c + (1 | Subject) + (1 | Word), 
                  family = inverse.gaussian(link = "log"), data = lexdec)

# bootstrapping always fails on the model with identity link 
confint(object = mod1.id, parm = "beta_", method = "boot") 

# when using the log link, bootstrapping does seem to work but results do not correspond to lmer above
confint(object = mod1.log, parm = "beta_", method = "boot") # takes some minutes! 

# result: [2.5%, 97.5%]  =  [-5.05, 2.58] # exponentiating these values does not correspond at all to [-38, -21] obtained above with lmer
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a different way to get bootstrapped CI's for `glmer` models with an identity link?
2. If not, how can I back transform the results from the model with the log link to original units?
3. If 2 above also does not solve the problem, should I report Wald based CI's or is it preferable to just not report any CI in this case?

Comment: Personally, when needing a Gamma GLMM with identity link, I have had good experiences with Bayesian models. I've had less convergence/numerical issues and you can derive credible intervals easily. I like the rstanarm package for its ease of use.